# How can I add an EC2 instance that I already have running to an Amazon OpsWorks stack?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How can I add an EC2 instance that I already have running to an Amazon OpsWorks stack?

I just want to be able to manually run recipes on it for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the current OpsWorks system. Even if you could, it would require the server to have the OpsWorks agent and Chef to be installed, which is handled already in the OpsWorks AMIs provided by Amazon.

A bit late, but I thought I'd give it an answer.